# Access to XMLHttpRequest at .' from origin . has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: django, angular, api

I build my API using Django and try to use this API from angular but I get a CORS policy error.
Below is my code. Since I am new to both Django and angular, I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with the issue.

Django settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'bd_api',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken' ,
    'django.contrib.sites' ,
    'allauth' ,
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders' ,
    ]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:4200',
]
SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
...
```

Angular codes files

environments.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api"
};
```

intercept.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
});
const reqWithToken = request.clone({headers});
return next.handle(reqWithToken);

}
}
```

http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpserviceService {

  baseUrl = environment.api_url;
  // headers = {Authorization: true}
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getContries(cond=''){
    if(cond != '')
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/country?'+cond);
    else
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/country');
  }
}
```

calling the api from this method present in my main.component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private httpService: HttpserviceService) { }

this.httpService.getContries().subscribe((resp) =>{
      console.log('getcontriessss', resp);
      if(resp['result'].length > 0){
        this.dropdownOptions = [];
        resp['result'].forEach(element => {
          this.dropdownOptions = [...this.dropdownOptions, {id: element.short_name, name: element.name}]
        });
      }else{

      }
    });
```

but I am getting this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/country' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone.js:3324 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/country net::ERR_FAILED
core.js:4127 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/country", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/country: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/country"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I tried to find out the solution but could not understand where the problem is comming from. Is it from my Django files or angular files.

Answer (score 0):

For the development, you can simply add the proxy config to your `package.json` or `webpack.config.js`. No need for `corsheaders`. Also, you can use some extensions in your browser or disable the security however it's not recommended. And for deployment, it depends on how you want to deploy your app. If both will run on the same port there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the line `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to your `settings.py` may solve your problem. But be careful about it in your production settings. Maybe adding the following to your `settings.py` is a more secure way:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    INSTALLED_APPS.append(
        'corsheaders'
    ) # if you haven't this app in your installed apps
    MIDDLEWARE.append(
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ) # if you haven't this app in your installed apps
```

So by changing the debug mode of your project, it's `cors` settings will be inactive too.

Comment: for the testing purpose even by adding CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW=True does not remove the error and i still get the error

Comment: can you move the line `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to the end of your `settings.py` and see if it works? And please restart your server after doing this.

Comment: make sure it is `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` not `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW=True` .

Comment: I did according to your instruction, but still see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST**

```
# ============= Cores Header Origin ====================
    
    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
    
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
        'http://localhost:4200',
        'http://localhost:8000'
    )
```